# How to return a list containing common elements with no duplicates

Tags: python

```
def common_elements(list1, list2):
    """
    Return a list containing the elements which are in both list1 and list2

    >>> common_elements([1,2,3,4,5,6], [3,5,7,9])
    [3, 5]
    >>> common_elements(["this","this","n","that"],["this","not","that","that"])
    ['this', 'that']
    """

    result = []
    for element in list1:
        if element in list2:
            result.append(element)
    return result
```

I have this so far but it returns with duplicates for example:

```
common_elements(["this","this","n","that"],["this","not","that","that"])
```

Returns as: `['this', 'this', 'that']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> b = [3,5,7,9]
>>> list(set(a).intersection(b))
[3, 5]
```

**EDIT**: Don't need to convert b to a set. Thanks @Johnsyweb

Comment: `set.intersection()` works with *any* iterable, so it's not necessary to convert `b` to a `set`! [gnibbler's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039009/how-to-return-a-list-containing-common-elements-with-no-duplicates/6039046#6039046) is better.

Answer (score 6):

Using `set.intersection()` because it means that it is not necessary to convert `list2` to a set

```
def common_elements(list1, list2):
    return set(list1).intersection(list2)
```

It is more efficient to choose the shorter list to convert to a set

```
def common_elements(list1, list2):
    short_list, long_list = sorted((list1, list2), key=len)
    return set(short_list).intersection(long_list)
```

of course to return a list, you would use

```
    return list(set(...))
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [sets](http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html):

```
>>> a, b = [1,2,3,4,5,6], [3,5,7,9]
>>> set(a).intersection(b)
set([3, 5])
```

Comment: `set.intersection()` works with any iterable, so it's not necessary to convert `b` to a `set`

Comment: @gnibbler:  Thanks, didn't remember that.  Updated my answer, and upvoted yours.

Answer (score 3):

```
def common_elements(a, b):
    return list(set(a) & set(b))
```

In this case, we are taking the intersection of two sets, which are in turn constructed from the two lists. Each set consists of the unique items in each list. We finally convert back to a list because that's the desired return type.

Answer (score 0):

You want to work with sets, as they have some pretty nice operations:

```
>>> a = set([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> b = set([3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> a.intersection(b)
set([3, 4])
>>> a.difference(b)
set([1, 2])
>>> b.intersection(a)
set([5, 6])
>>> a.union(b)
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```